# mysql_close is not working

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-connect

i want to close an opened connection using mysql_close()
but when i go at my server and check the amoutn od opened connections in my server the connections are increased!
for example i have 100 opened connections in my mysql data base

and i have a page with this code:

```
<?php include "configa/configuration.php";
$con = mysql_connect($sql['host'],$sql['user'],$sql['password']);
if ($con) echo "connected<br>";
mysql_close($con);  
if (!$con) echo "disconnected";
?>
```

every time i refresh page a new connection is initialized and only connectid shows up in page.
what could possibly be wrong

in this way with 1000 page refresh my sql server gets disconnected

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

`Connection.close()` actually doesn't remove the connection from connection pool. try using `Connection.Dispose()` to release the connection completely. But you can't open that dispose connection again so take care before closing it.

More about close: [Close](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-close)
Or you can set the connection pooling to false.

Comment: thanks for quick reply!!! how i can do that? (im newbie at programming) im using php

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/apis-php-ref.mysql.html#apis-php-function.mysql-connect Check here for php syntax. I don't know about php :P

Comment: mysql_close actually closes the connection, since thats what i read all over the internet.... anyone has an idea??

Comment: yes! you are right. but the problem is connection pool. So try to set connectionPooling to false.

Comment: can u explain please? how can i do that?

Comment: still nothing conenctions increase in every refresh but sysntax is ok!!

Answer (score 0):

The "Connections" value from the SHOW STATUS is essentially a counter of the number of connections that have been made to the MySQL server since it was started; it's not the number of currently open connections.

To show the current connections (those that are still open), use

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```